# Did I derive a new form of the gamma function?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, factorial, gamma-function

I wish to extend the factorial to non-integer arguments in a unique way, given the following conditions:

1. $n!=n(n-1)!$
2. $1!=1$

---

To anyone interested in viewing the final form before reading the whole post:

> $$x!=\exp\left[\int_0^x\left(-\gamma+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}dt\right)d\phi\right]$$

---

> $$f(x):=\ln(x!)$$

$$f(x)=\ln(x!)=\ln(x)+\ln((x-1)!)=\ln(x)+f(x-1)$$

$$f(x)=f(x-1)+\ln(x)$$

$$\frac d{dx}f(x)=\frac d{dx}f(x-1)+\ln(x)$$

$$f'(x)=f'(x-1)+\frac1x\tag1$$

$$f'(x)=f'(x-2)+\frac1{x-1}+\frac1x$$

$$=f'(0)+1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1x$$

for $x\in\mathbb N$:

> $$f'(x)=f'(0)+\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1n\tag2$$

Euler has a nice extension of the harmonic numbers to non-integer arguments,

$$f'(x)=f'(0)+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt\tag{2.1}$$

from the FTOC we have

$$\ln(x!)=\int_0^x\left(f'(0)+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}dt\right)d\phi$$

> $$x!=\exp\left[\int_0^x\left(f'(0)+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}dt\right)d\phi\right]\tag3$$

And with $f'(0)=-\gamma$, the Euler mascheroni constant, we should get the gamma function.  Or we may just let it sit as an unknown parameter.

---

My questions are if this captures all possible extensions of the factorial with the given conditions, since, if it did, it'd be a pretty good general extension to the factorial?

Given a few more assumptions, it is easy enough to set bounds to what $f'(0)$ might be as well.

Notably, this representation fails when considering $\Re(x)\le-1$, but coupled with the first condition, it is extendable to all $x$, except of course the negative integers.

> robjohn♦ notes an extension to the harmonic numbers that converges for $x\in\mathbb C$, except the negative integers:
>
> $$\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+\phi}\right)$$

Any suggestions on things I could've improved and flaws in this would be nice.

---

Edit:

Using the second condition and $x=1$, we may have

$$1=\exp\left[\int_0^1\left(f'(0)+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}dt\right)d\phi\right]$$

$$\implies f'(0)=-\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}dt\ d\phi$$

$$f'(0)=-\gamma$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-mascheroni constant.

Using this we get a new form of the gamma function(?):

> $$\boxed{x!=\exp\left[\int_0^x\left(-\gamma+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}dt\right)d\phi\right]}\tag4$$

$$=\exp\left[\int_0^x\left(-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+\phi}\right)\right)d\phi\right]$$

---

I'm not sure how to deal with trivial manipulations of this expression, as surely someone is gonna say "hey, just multiply everything by $(1+\sin(2\pi x))$ and it will still satisfy the conditions, right?"

But regardless, I think this is a pretty cool new gamma function?

---

Also, references to this if it's not new.

If someone could make a graph of this to look at, you would be great.

Comment: Hm... why the vote to close as off-topic?

Comment: Have you tried plotting it against the usual gamma function?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I don't know how to... my usual graphing calculators won't except this.  For WolframAlpha, the computation time is exceeded.  If you could provide a plot, that'd be great.

Comment: Since you seem to be interested in this sort of thing, you might want to see [this](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunctionMJ.html), too.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I have no idea how you would implement that

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Hm, I have no idea.  But how would you even do a product integral?!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not new, though I would like to offer another derivation;
\begin{align*}
            \int_{0}^{t}H_ydy &= \int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^y}{1-x}dxdy\\
                              &= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1-x^y}{1-x}dydx\\
                              &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t}{1-x}+\frac{1-x^t}{(1-x)\ln(x)}dx\\
                              (1)&= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t}{1-x}+\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}\frac{x^j}{\ln(x)}dx\\
                              &=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\left( -t\ln(1-x)+\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}\text{li}(x^{j+1})\right)\\
                              (2)&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}\left(\text{li}(x^{j+1})-\ln(1-x)\right)\\
                              &= \gamma t + \sum_{j=0}^{t-1}\ln(j+1)\\
                              &= \gamma t + \ln(t!)\\
                              &= \gamma t +\ln\Gamma(t+1)
        \end{align*}

Now writing $H_y$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y}{n(n+y)}$ gives
        \begin{align*}
        \int_{0}^{t}H_ydy &= \gamma t + \ln\Gamma(t+1)\\
                          &= \int_{0}^{t}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y}{n(n+y)}dy\\
                          &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t}{n}-\ln \left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)
    \end{align*}
solving for $\Gamma(t+1)$ and using $\Gamma(t+1) = t\Gamma(t)$ gives
        $$\Gamma(t) = \frac{e^{-\gamma t}}{t}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{\frac{t}{n}}$$

**EDIT**
First, I should say that I am just starting to study analysis - I just try stuff and see if it works, so I apologize for the lack of rigour.

I'm not too sure which steps I should fill in, so I will try to fill in any apparent holes.

assuming we only know that $\gamma$ shows up as
 $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}(H_N - \ln(N)) = \gamma,$$
one can show that $\int_{0}^{1}H_ydy=\gamma$ using $H_y=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\zeta(k)y^{k-1}$ for $|y|<1$ (I have a crude derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1946918/115791)).

Knowing that, we get
\begin{align*}
\gamma = \int_{0}^{1}H_ydy &= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^y}{1-x}dxdy\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{x^y}{1-x}dydx\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\ln(x)}dx\\
(*)&= \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}(\text{li}(x)-\ln(1-x)),\\
\end{align*}
where $\text{li}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\ln(t)}dt$ is the logarithmic integral.

Now we need to evaluate $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x^k}{\ln(x)}dx$ for (1); Make the substitution $\;x=e^u$ to get
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x^k}{\ln(x)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\ln(t)}\frac{e^{(k+1)u}}{u}du,$$
now let $v=(k+1)u$ and see that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x^k}{\ln(x)}dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{(k+1)\ln(t)}\frac{e^x}{x}dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{t^{k+1}}\frac{1}{\ln(x)}dx\\
&=\text{li}(t^{k+1})
\end{align*}
after the substitution $x=\ln(u)$.

Next we need to evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}(\text{li}(x^k)-\ln(1-x))$.
so by using $(*)$ -
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}(\text{li}(x^k)-\ln(1-x)) &= \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}(\text{li}(x) - \ln(1-\sqrt[k]{x})\\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\left(\text{li}(x) - \ln \left(\frac{1-x}{1+\sqrt[k]{x} + \cdots +\sqrt[k]{x^{k-1}}}\right)\right)\\
&= \gamma + \ln(k)
\end{align*}

I just have to say that I really like how you derived it.

Comment: Ah, nice, so we reach the Weierstrass definition of the gamma function?  Nice catch.  Perhaps a reference would be nice.

Comment: This is something I came up with a few days ago, actually. I feel for OP because I thought it was new too

Comment: XD No, wait, but was it new before you?!  I'm trying to read up on this.

Comment: Oh sorry. Its just where ive been typing up my notes from when i started studying the harmonic numbers. Im off to work so i will find a way to post it later if you'd like.

Comment: Sure thing, take your time. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Many skipped steps I cannot jump over easily.  When you get the chance, please explain a bit more.  Thank you.

Comment: While I have a few seconds, i just wanted to let you know that desmos is capable of plotting integrals and that during my break i will fill in the missing steps.

Comment: Yeah, but then my computer freezes.  :'(  There are integrals it can do easily, but trying double integrals?  My computer doesn't like that.

Comment: Hopefully the edit clears up any questions, and what I meant by my earlier comment was that I thought the infinite product representation of the gamma function was something that I could call my own, but I very quickly found it on the gamma function wikipedia page.

Comment: That was quite nice to read through.  I'll give you this for the nice effort you put in (never mind the first sentence after '**EDIT**').  Also, thank you for the last remark.  $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 13):

**Integral of the Logarithmic Derivative of Gamma**

The logarithmic derivative of the Gamma function is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):
$$
\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}=\psi(x)=-\gamma+H_{x-1}\tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(\Gamma(x))
&=\int_1^x\left(-\gamma+H_{\phi-1}\right)\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&=\int_1^x\left(-\gamma+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^{\phi-1}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&=\int_0^{x-1}\left(-\gamma+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\phi}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathrm{d}\phi\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Verification of the Gamma Function**

The [Bohr-Mollerup Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) says that the Gamma function is uniquely determined as the log-convex function so that $\Gamma(1)=1$ and $\Gamma(x+1)=x\,\Gamma(x)$.

We can verify these assuming only $H_x-H_{x-1}=\frac1x$ and $H'_x\ge0$.

$\boldsymbol{\Gamma(1)=1}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\log(\Gamma(1))
&=\int_1^1\left(-\gamma+H_{\phi-1}\right)\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&=0\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
$\boldsymbol{\Gamma(x+1)=x\,\Gamma(x)}$: Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(H_n-\log(n)\right)=\gamma$ and $H_n-\frac1n\le\int_{n-1}^nH_\phi\,\mathrm{d}\phi\le H_n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(\Gamma(x+1))-\log(\Gamma(x))
&=\int_x^{x+1}\left(-\gamma+H_{\phi-1}\right)\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&=-\gamma+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_x^nH_{\phi-1}\,\mathrm{d}\phi-\int_{x+1}^nH_{\phi-1}\,\mathrm{d}\phi\right)\\
&=-\gamma+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_x^nH_{\phi-1}\,\mathrm{d}\phi-\int_x^{n-1}H_\phi\,\mathrm{d}\phi\right)\\
&=-\gamma+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\int_x^n\frac1\phi\,\mathrm{d}\phi+\int_{n-1}^nH_\phi\,\mathrm{d}\phi\right)\\[6pt]
&=-\gamma+\log(x)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\log(n)+H_n\right)\\[8pt]
&=\log(x)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
**$\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$ is log-convex**:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\log(\Gamma(x))
&=H'_{x-1}\\
&\ge0\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Verifying the Necessary Properties of the Extension**
$$
\begin{align}
H_x-H_{x-1}
&=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_0^1\frac{1-t^{x-1}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^1t^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac1x\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
H'_x
&=\int_0^1\frac{-\log(t)t^x}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\ge0\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Limitations of the Extension**

One limitation of the extension
$$
H_x=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{8}
$$
is that it doesn't converge for $\mathrm{Re}(x)\le-1$.

An extension of the Harmonic Numbers that works for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$ is
$$
H_x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x}\right)\tag{9}
$$

Comment: Ok, but how do I relate the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function to the more general factorial?  The use of the gamma function to set a relationship to the harmonic numbers isn't what I was really looking for..

Comment: The extension of the Harmonic numbers you presents is nice, but I honestly chose the integral form for faster convergence.

Comment: Judging from your question, you know that for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$, so the natural extension is $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$; that is how you relate the logarithmic derivative of the Gamma function to the more general factorial. Nowhere do I use the Gamma function to set up a relation to the Harmonic Numbers, but as you do, I use the extended Harmonic Numbers and their relationship to the digamma function to derive a formula for the logarithm of the Gamma function. This relationship is well known and so I thought it was relevant to your question.

Comment: I mean, sure, yes, but you assume I speak of $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$.  It could've been very well that my extension were not equal to the gamma function at all, making this more of a side note to me.

Comment: I had included a section on showing that the function you present is indeed the Gamma function, but didn't know if it would be relevant. Since you mention it, I will put that back when I get back to my computer (entering MathJax on the phone is tedious and error-prone).

Comment: Yeah, definitely.  $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Um, was $(4)$ necessary?  Why not just do $\log(\Gamma(x+1))-\log(\Gamma(x))=\log\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x)}=\log(x)$?

Comment: @SimpleArt: that is the property we are trying to verify about $\Gamma$ defined in this way. The whole point of that section is verifying that $\Gamma$ is the $\Gamma$ we all know and love.

Comment: Ah, quite beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Weierstrass definition of the Gamma function in disguise. Note that $$\Gamma(z)=\frac{e^{-\gamma z}}z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{z/n}}{1+\frac zn}$$We can re-write this as $$\frac{e^{-\gamma z}}z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{z/n}}{1+\frac zn}=e^{\log\left(\frac{e^{-\gamma z}}z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{z/n}}{1+\frac zn}\right)}=\frac1ze^{-\gamma z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(z/k-\log(1+z/k))}$$$-\gamma z=-\int_0^z\gamma dx$ while the infinite sum is $\int_0^zH_xdx$ by using $H_x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac x{n(n+x)}$.

PS: The only way I was able to answer this was because I had written the Gamma function in a similar way to solve $\int_0^1\Gamma(1+z)dz$ and then used the Taylor series expansion of the exponential function, but I realized that method was not going to work.

Edit: I just realized that one of the answerers also thought this was a new formula and I derived it too as I said above. Nice coincidence.