# Is this differentiation of factorial valid?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factorial

I have an expression like:
$$\frac{d(n(x)!)^{-1}}{dx}$$ where $n(x)$ is given by $n(x)=floor(x \exp(-c))$ now can I do this like $-1(n(x))^{-2}(n(x)-1)(n(x)-1)! \frac{dn(x)}{dx}$ where i am using the method of finite differences and also some reference from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300526/derivative-of-a-factorial). Is this the correct way?

Just one edit: **Will it make a significant difference if we have partial derivative with respect to x rather then differentiation?**

Comment: What? How  did you derive the factorial function? Did you mean gamma function?

Comment: Tried using finite difference method.

Comment: But the factorial is a discrete function, you cannot derive it

Comment: I am looking in this question [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-derivative-of-x)

Comment: @OfekGillon I think you mean "differentiate", not "derive".

Comment: @Ankit The floor-function is not differentiable at integers.

Comment: Is there a way by which I can get approximate answer for this? I am actually  doing differentiation wrt x, but the problem is this in the bigger function factorial comes, which unfortunately is a function of x. Now I do not know what to do, how should I solve the differentiation.

Comment: note that the floor function between consecutive integer will be constant hence the first derivation is zero. Just look for intervals $n(x)!$ is constant. Also note that $$d(n(x)!)^{-1}/dx=(d(n(x)!)/dx) / (n(x)!)^2$$ if differentiable.

Comment: [Differentiating factorials I hear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958762/did-i-derive-a-new-form-of-the-gamma-function)

Answer (score 0):

The floor function is not differentiable, but you can try something with the gamma function $\Gamma$, which for integers satisfy

$$
\Gamma(n) = (n - 1)!
$$
In this case, your then problem becomes finding the derivative

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} x}(\Gamma(f(x) + 1))^{-1}
$$

where

$$
f(x) = x e^{-c}
$$

Hope it helps

Comment: So you mean floor(x) in the interval $0<x<1$ is not differentiable which is not true.

Comment: in the question for all integer $n$, if $ne^c<x<(n+1)e^c$ then the first derivative is zero. and for all points $x=ne^c$ is not differentiable.